# C# create a new exchange email with properties like deliverydate

Tags: c#, email, properties, exchange-server, lotus

I'm looking for exchange email creation for a migration lotus to exchange platform.

I can create email body with Body property of an EmailMessage Object, but I can only Get DateTimeCreated property and not set it.

What I want, is to get my lotus email, convert it to exchange format with all properties, and save it to my exchange server.

regards

Comment: Can you get the Message in Mime Format is so that will be easier to upload and you won't have to worry about the received date see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672319(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: nop, I'm using domino.interop to get my emails

I'm able to get all email in string format:  
  
_0: Principal  CN=Admin Administrateur/O=xxx_  
_1: OriginalModTime  18/12/2015 15:27:51_  
_2: InetSendTo  CN=myName myName/O=myDomain_  
_3: InetCopyTo _   
_4: $StorageTo  1_  
_5: $Orig  6A080B6A6BBACA39C1257F1F004F70CD_  
etc...

Comment: Well you could use the information you get from domino and use another class library to build a MimeMessage based on that and then upload it.